# How to check the winner in TICTACTOE Game? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a problem with checking the winner.

Here's to show my HTML for play area:

```
   <div class="play-area gray pointerEvents">
            <div id="block_0" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_1" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_2" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_3" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_4" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_5" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_6" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_7" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_8" class="block"></div>
          </div>
```

Here's the function of how I turn the player from player 1 to 2.

```
    boxes.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                //dispalay x and o.
        currentPlayer();
    })

    function currentPlayer(){
        if (turn % 2 === 1){
            event.target.innerHTML = activePlayer1;
            turn++;
        }else{
            event.target.innerHTML = activePlayer2;
            turn--;
        }
    }
```

Now I need to check the winner using function as well and here's what I only got I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
function checkingWinner(){
        let winningCombos = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6],
            [1, 4, 7],
            [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8],
            [2, 4, 6]
        ];
  }
```

I'll appreciate your time answering this, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to write a final answer as it seems you are trying to learn something here so I'll only point some tips that will lead you to a solution.
What I would do if you want to check your game board for a winner is :

First : Track the state of where did each player made a move. This can be done by giving your onClick callback a parameter saying which tile has been clicked so that   you know where "x" and "o" are. For example in an array of size 9 where it can have 3 values "undefined" if no one checked that tile, "1" or "2" representing player one or 2.

Then: When you want to check for your winner just compare all your winning combos with that state and determine if there is a winner or not. For example

```
if state[0] + state[1] + state[2] === 3 {
    console.log("player 1 wins")
} 
// etc
```

The reason you do not know where to start your win function is because you do not have anything to compare your winning combos against, tracking the state of the board will help you to clarify that.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just starting to learn javascript that's why I am still doing some research and trial / error method. haha! Your comment has been very heplful. :)

Comment: Best way to learn is to make mistakes, that means you are doing something. ^^

Answer (score 1):

With `array.some` you can check if any of the combo's are correct

```js
const data = [
  "X", "O", "X",
  "O", "X", "X",
  "X", "O", "O"
];

const winningCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

// Check if one of the combos is correct
const hasWinner = winningCombos.some(combo => {
  // Check of every cell in the combo is the same
  return combo.every(cell => data[cell] === "X") || combo.every(cell => data[cell] === "O");
});

console.log(hasWinner);
```

Comment: You've been very helpful @theblackgigant :)